# Unable to set default Time Range in Azure dashboard(All Users) created from Azure Monitor Workbooks

Tags: azure, kql, azure-dashboard, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have used Azure monitor workbooks to create dashboards for Alerts history and to view active alerts. Also added Time Picker parameter to set the time range from the dashboard and it works without any issues. But seems like Users who are having read-only rights to the dashboard are unable to set the time range due to read only permissions. Anyone had this experience?

1. Can we achieve this without providing write access permissions for dashboard users?

   or
2. Is it possible to set default time range to Azure dashboard (May be from workbook(Not in query) and pin the tiles in Azure dashboard)), so that it'll be applied for all the read only users and rest may be who ever having write access they can choose the time range.

Your input on this is really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: i've forwarded this to the Azure Portal dashboard team, it seems odd that a read-only user can't change the time range of a dashboard. (to me it would seem like they should just not be able to save any changes?)

Comment: Yeah your thought also fine but time picker is not a global parameter which will apply to all the users whoever accessing. It’s individual so I feel like it should be excluded from read only permissions.